# How do I efficiently setup a Linux crontab to run a script every Saturday of the month except the first Saturday

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I want to run a script every Saturday except for the first Saturday of each month. (The script monitors a maintenance window, and the window is longer on the first Saturday of the month.)

Here is what I have:

```
*/15 17-18 8-31 * * [ "$(date '+\%a')" = "Sat" ] && <Then run my script>
```

Here is what I'm looking at:

```
*/15 17-18 *    * 6 [ "$(date '+\%d')" > "7" ] && <Then run my script>
```

I feel like the first example creates too many unnecessary attempts as it runs every day after the first seven days of the month but only will process the monitoring script on Saturdays.

In the second example, I'm attempting to run the script only on Saturdays but only if the day of the month is greater than 7. I'm not sure how to do it using the 'day of the month' result from the `date` command, and I'm not sure if this will work. Specifically, should I use the '>' symbol or a 'gt' bash-like function?

Is there a better way to achieve this other than what I have here?

Thanks for your input. I've looked at other examples similar to this but most of them only addressed running a script on the first weekend of the month.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
*/15 17-18 * * 6 [ $(date '+\%d') -gt 7 ] && <Then run your script>
```

---

From `help test`:

> `-gt`: greater-than

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had considered the `-gt` comparison as stated above but every example I had seen used actual conditionals.  I ran a test over the weekend and the code worked. I'll try the -gt as well just to see if it works. 
`*/15 17-18 *    * 6 [ "$(date '+\%d')" > "7" ] && <Then run my script>`

Comment: Thanks again for your input. I've found the `-gt` does nothing in chrontab within this context. This makes me think that it is a valid syntax that is always false.

Comment: With `"$(date '+\%d')" > "7"` you redirect stdout of `date '+%d'` to a file named `7`.

Comment: That's what I thought would happen as well, but it appears to be working correctly. I will see if I can track down the `7` file and do some more tests. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Good call Cyrus. It works, sort of. But, the condition `[ "$(date '+\%d')" > "7" ]` is always true and it creates a touch file in the `/home/user` directory. Using `-gt` works as expected. Thanks for your input.